# How can I use a table without using owner?

Tags: sql, sql-server, owner

[image: 1]
Look that the owner and the user are the same. I need to know what is the correct configuration I have to do.

Comment: Please, don't post images like that.

Answer (score 0):

this is not owner , you are referring to schema.

sql server had "dbo" as It's default schema for all the user ,

however you can change the default schema for user permanently

using :

```
ALTER USER userName WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = { schemaName | NULL }
```

but I recommend , you always use schemanaem.objectname to avoid further issues